# Javascript to fetch image src and other info not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

So, just like the title says, I've written code to load the info from a json and show it on a *SUPER* simple HTML page. All I want is for it to show the image, title and have a button to load a new image. The problem is that only the button shows up.

What am I missing here?

**Javascript**

```
// function to output the image to the page with the title and description
function output(comic_info) {
    let article = document.createElement("article");
    let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.innerHTML = comic_info.title;
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = comic_info.img;
    img.alt = comic_info.alt;
    article.appendChild(h3);
    article.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("comics").appendChild(article);
}

// fetch the info from the url about the comic
async function getComic(comic_url) {
    const response = await fetch(comic_url);
    // check that fetch is successful
    if (response.ok) {
        comic_info = await response.json();
        output(comic_info);
    }
}

// get a different comic's info
function getNewComic() {
    let random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    let comic_url = "https://xkcd.com/" + random_number + "/info.0.json";
    getComic(comic_url);
}

// when a button is clicked, get a new comic
document.getElementById("new_comic").addEventListener("click", getNewComic);
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <!-- div to add comic image and info to the page -->
            <div id="comics">
            </div>

            <!-- button to choose new comic -->
            <button id="new_comic">New Comic</button>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        &copy;<span id="year"></span> | Project | Lesson 06
    </footer>
    <script src="/week06/student_files/scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/week06/w06_project.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked the `output()` is invoked?

Comment: Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them. Look for errors both in the Chrome inspector Javascript console as well as the network tab.

Comment: Once you find the error, you'll need to work around the CORs issue. You must familiarize yourself with CORs. It's going to be more complicated than what you're doing, you can't do it from a simple HTML file. Here's an article explaining your issue: https://dev.to/will_yama/how-to-overcome-cors-errors-2nh9

Comment: After you know you have data in comic_info (maybe at the top of the output function), console.log(JSON.stringify(comic_info)); Then look at the actual structure of the object in the console to make sure your assumptions about completeness and paths are correct.

Comment: I have a feeling that `getNewComic()` doesn't even get invoked upon click. What does your HTML look like, where in your HTML are you placing the script tag, and did you find any errors in the browser dev console (open with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K`)?

Comment: OP do not provide html code,so we do not knwo `comics` and `new_comic` exists or not

Comment: <button id="newComic">New Comic</button> is inconsistent with your getElementById('new_comic') statement - both ids should be the same (new_comic or newComic)

Comment: Aha, I was correct. The HTML's ID for the button is `newComic`, while in your JS you're querying `new_comic`. The button event would not fire.

Comment: So, I fixed the issues with the incorrect button ID, and that didn't seem to do anything. I've tried just setting a variable for the getComic function to use and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Checking the console gives all sorts of issues, I'm not even sure where to start with it really.

Comment: Looking over it, most of the error messages are from CORS problems. I'm not sure what CORS is yet, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code. The problem that you are facing is because of something called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You can access the data from the website, of course, since you are using their own website and the server serves you with the data that you requested.
But when you try to fetch the same information from your code, it's a different story since you are running the code on `localhost`, which is not recognized by the server. That's why the server blocks your request and sends you nothing.

```js
if (response.ok) {
    comic_info = await response.json();
    output(comic_info);
  }
```

The `output` function never gets called since `response.ok` is not `true/truthy` because the server has blocked your request. The only way you can pull this off is

1. Make numerous requests to the same url from your browser and save the response in a `json` file and then randomly choose one and output that specific comic.
2. Or you have to find other website that allows Cross-Origin Request Sharing(CORS).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like clicking the button does fire the getNewComic function, which does generate a valid URL, and then calls the getComic function successfully. The response variable is never defined, as the fetch doesn't seem to return. Dropping console.logs at the beginning of each function with the variables attached helps trace where things stop working, for example:

```
async function getComic(comic_url) {
  console.log('In getComic', comic_url);
```

That returns a valid URL to the console, so we know it gets that far, but the fetch doesn't seem to return. If you drop a console.log after the fetch, it never gets called.

You could mock up the object by fetching the URL directly in a browser and assigning it to a variable in order to troubleshoot the rest of the project, and then return to the fetch at the end. Comment out the fetch so it doesn't stall the function, then manually assign valid JSON to the response variable.

For example:

```
  // const response = await fetch(comic_url);
  const response = {
    month: '7',
    num: 1234,
    link: '',
    year: '2013',
    news: '',
    safe_title: 'Douglas Engelbart (1925-2013)',
    transcript:
      'San Francisco, December 9th, 1968: \n[[We see a figure talking into a headset. It\'s a fair assumption that it\'s Douglas Engelbart.]]\nDouglas: ... We generated video signals with a cathode ray tube... We have a pointing device we call a "mouse"... I can "copy" text... ... and we have powerful join file editing... underneath the file here we can exchange "direct messages"...\n\n[[Douglas continues to narrate. Some music is playing.]]\nDouglas: ... Users can share files... ... files which can encode audio samples, using our "masking codecs"... The file you\'re hearing now is one of my own compositions...\nMusic: I heard there was a secret chord\n\n[[Douglas continues to narrate.]]\nDouglas: ... And you can superimpose text on the picture of the cat, like so... This cat is saying "YOLO", which stands for "You Only Live Once"... ...Just a little acronym we thought up...\n\n{{Title text: Actual quote from The Demo: \'... an advantage of being online is that it keeps track of who you are and what you\u00e2\u0080\u0099re doing all the time ...\'}}',
    alt: "Actual quote from The Demo: '... an advantage of being online is that it keeps track of who you are and what you\u2019re doing all the time ...'",
    img: 'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/douglas_engelbart_1925_2013.png',
    title: 'Douglas Engelbart (1925-2013)',
    day: '5',
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Work through the rest of the project and see if you can get the html construction parts working with data you know is valid, and then return to the fetch later.

It's possible that xkcd explicitly prohibits code from fetching data without permission, which would explain the CORS errors you're getting. CORS is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, and it's a mechanism to determine who is allowed to access resources from a server, identified by ip, port, domain etc., and is specifically to prevent someone from embedding content from someone else's server without permission. If that's the case, unless you get permission from xkcd (which is unlikely if they have locked that down), then you'll want to find another source for content for this project.